# Not able to access camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I am not able to access camera in my activity.getting error in takepicture method how I solve it.
CamTestActivity

```
public class CamTestActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "CamTestActivity";
    Preview preview;
    Button buttonClick;
    Camera camera;
    Activity act;
    Context ctx;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ctx = this;
        act = this;
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        preview = new Preview(this, (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView));
        preview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout)).addView(preview);
        preview.setKeepScreenOn(true);

        preview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
            }
        });

        Toast.makeText(ctx, getString(R.string.take_photo_help), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //      buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
        //      
        //      buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        //          public void onClick(View v) {
        ////                preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        //              camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        //          }
        //      });
        //      
        //      buttonClick.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){
        //          @Override
        //          public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
        //              camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback(){
        //                  @Override
        //                  public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
        //                      //camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        //                  }
        //              });
        //              return true;
        //          }
        //      });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        int numCams = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        if(numCams > 0){
            try{
                camera = Camera.open(0);
                camera.startPreview();
                preview.setCamera(camera);
            } catch (RuntimeException ex){
                Toast.makeText(ctx, getString(R.string.camera_not_found), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if(camera != null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            preview.setCamera(null);
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void resetCam() {
        camera.startPreview();
        preview.setCamera(camera);
    }

    private void refreshGallery(File file) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
        sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {
            //           Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
        }
    };

    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            //           Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
        }
    };

    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            new SaveImageTask().execute(data);
            resetCam();
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
        }
    };

    private class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... data) {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;

            // Write to SD Card
            try {
                File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/camtest");
                dir.mkdirs();               

                String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
                File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);

                outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                outStream.write(data[0]);
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();

                Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length + " to " + outFile.getAbsolutePath());

                refreshGallery(outFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Preview.java

```
class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private final String TAG = "Preview";

    SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Size mPreviewSize;
    List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    Camera mCamera;

    Preview(Context context, SurfaceView sv) {
        super(context);

        mSurfaceView = sv;
//        addView(mSurfaceView);

        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        mCamera = camera;
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            requestLayout();

            // get Camera parameters
            Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

            List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
            if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
                // set the focus mode
                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
                // set Camera parameters
                mCamera.setParameters(params);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // We purposely disregard child measurements because act as a
        // wrapper to a SurfaceView that centers the camera preview instead
        // of stretching it.
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        if (changed && getChildCount() > 0) {
            final View child = getChildAt(0);

            final int width = r - l;
            final int height = b - t;

            int previewWidth = width;
            int previewHeight = height;
            if (mPreviewSize != null) {
                previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
                previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
            }

            // Center the child SurfaceView within the parent.
            if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth) {
                final int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height / previewHeight;
                child.layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0,
                        (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
            } else {
                final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
                child.layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2,
                        width, (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
            }
        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
    }


    private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (sizes == null) return null;

        Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        if(mCamera != null) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            requestLayout();

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    }

}
```

this is logcat.

```
12-15 15:10:10.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1857): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-15 15:10:10.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1857): Process: com.example.cam, PID: 1857
12-15 15:10:10.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1857): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(android.hardware.Camera$ShutterCallback, android.hardware.Camera$PictureCallback, android.hardware.Camera$PictureCallback)' on a null object reference
12-15 15:10:10.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at com.example.cam.CamTestActivity$4.onClick(CamTestActivity.java:62)
12-15 15:10:10.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
12-15 15:10:10.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
12-15 15:10:10.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-15 15:10:10.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-15 15:10:10.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-15 15:10:10.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
12-15 15:10:10.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-15 15:10:10.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-15 15:10:10.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-15 15:10:10.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: what is in line 62 in Your CamTestActivity?

Comment: `camera.takePicture()` camera here looks to be NULL

Comment: camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);

Comment: where are you initializing "Camera camera" ?

Comment: it seems to be a life cycle problem. In Your onPause() method, You set the cam to null. So what happens is, first You initialzie it in OnResume() and then onPause() get called and the cam is null. Give it a try and comment this in onPause() out....

Comment: above on create method like this Camera camera;

Comment: i commented cammera = null in onpause() method still getting same error.

Comment: Your `onPause` code is fine, as you intialise the camera in `onResume`. The above comments about onPause are wrong. Is it possible that `Camera.getNumberOfCameras()` is returning 0? You should print a log for that scenario.

Comment: yes camera.getNumberOfCameras() gives 0 how i solve this problem?

Comment: did you add permission to access camera?

Comment: Do you solve this problem? i had a same problem today.

Comment: I had the same issue: I was using   

               Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

before            mcamera = Camera.open(); 

Please make sure you are not doing the same with camera methods.

Answer (score 3):

Following two reasons for this error:
1) You have not initialized camera:

```
mcamera = mcamera.open();
```

2) You have not given permissions in androidmanifest.xml file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared the permission for using the Camera Hardware in your Android manifest file? I ran across this error when I forgot the following line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```